# Sending laser sensor data on raspberry pi to Flask server

Tags: flask, raspberry-pi

So I'm trying to get my raspberry pi to send data from a laser sensor to my flask server and I keep [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hj5l3.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w39f.png)

I have the server already controlling a solenoid I just cant get the laser sensor data to display.

Comment: Please read [ask] and understand that pictures of code are unhelpful in your question - they cannot be run, or edited, or searched. Please also add some basic debugging info, like whether the mail message was printed or not and what it said. Thank you.